# Material-UI Button cannot trigger when Popover close

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI 4.11. I have set up a Popover component as well as a Button:

Popover and Button

```
<Popover
    id={id}
    open={open}
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    onClose={handleClose}
    anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "bottom",
        horizontal: "left"
    }}
    transformOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "left"
    }}
>
<SidebarDropdown />
</Popover>
```

```
<Button
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    onClick={handleAddProject}
>
+ADD PROJECT
</Button>
```

and their function:

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
}

const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null)
}
const open = Boolean(anchorEl)
const id = open ? "simple-popover" : undefined
```

```
const handleAddProject = () => {
    console.log("handleAddProject")
}
```

To trigger the button action, I have to close the Popover first by clicking anywhere outside the Popup and then click the button. This is two actions. Can make it to one step only? When I click the button, the popupover is close and the button action is triggered.

This Popover and Button are not on the same parent element.

**EDIT**

What I have tried at the beginning is:

```
const handleAddProject = () => {
    console.log("handleAddProject")
    setAnchorEl(null)
}

const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null)
}
```

So I want that when I click the button, the anchor is null and the popover then closes. However, it's not working.

It's working in this way:

```
const handleAddProject = () => {
    console.log("handleAddProject")
}
    
const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null)
    handleAddProject()
}
```

But this is not when I click 'add project' button and it triggers the Popover close.

The component structure is like below: Button1 and Popover have the same parent component, they're in the same level. Button2 is far away from the prent component. To trigger the action from Button1 and Button2 if the Popover is open with my original code. I have to close the popupover first and then click button1 or button2 again to trigger the button action. I want to know is there a way I can bind the close with the button together? So if I click the buttons, it will close the popover as well as trigger its own action?

[image]

Comment: Call `handleClose` inside `handleAddProject`. You may need to show your component structure if those callbacks aren't available to each other.

Comment: The first part of your edit makes no sense. Can you post a stackblitz for context?

Comment: I thought the popover is controlled by anchorEl so I set anchorEl to null on click action, but this is not working. even if I add ```setAnchorEl(null)``` to ```handleAddProject```, this add action cannot trigger when popover close. It's like the popover add a div at the top, so I cannot click any other elements before close it.

Comment: It is controlled by anchorEl, more accurately its controlled by open which is set to be Boolean(anchorEl) which is why what you’re saying above - it works when in one function but not the other - makes no sense. You’ll have to provide a minimal reproduction to get any more help

Comment: I'm not sure why ```Popover``` is not working well. Finally, I swith it to ```Popper```.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I get the component structure, do something like this:

Pass an `onSelect` prop into `SidebarDropdown`. When an option is chosen, make sure to call that prop. The job of that prop is to close the menu when an action is selected.

e.g.

```
<Popover
    id={id}
    open={open}
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    onClose={handleClose}
    anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "bottom",
        horizontal: "left"
    }}
    transformOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "left"
    }}
>
 <SidebarDropdown onSelect={handleClose} />
</Popover>
```

Comment: I have posted the structure.